# Testing a html class title tag with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, title

I have the following code in my app :

```rb
<div class="btn btn-mini disabled" title="<%= t('title.button.loan.borrow.disable.already_current') %>"><%= t('button.loan.borrow.after_confirmation') %></div>
```

I want to test the presence of this button on my page, taking in account the title tag. How can I do that ?

```rb
it { should have_css('.btn.disabled',
                     text: t('button.loan.borrow.after_confirmation'),
# (False line)       title: t('title.button.loan.borrow.disable.already_current')) }
```

Comment: Having three constraints on your expectation is perhaps overkill, and makes for a pretty brittle spec. You should perhaps consider using just enough constraints to check for the presence of the button, without fretting over the specific localizations used.

Comment: Daniel, I have multiple reason to display disabled button, and I want to explain them through the html title tag. But if I want to check that the title of my buttons are displayed accordingly to the context, I must test it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
it { should have_css(".btn.disabled[title='#{t('title.button.loan.borrow.disable.already_current')}']",
                 text: t('button.ownership.take.after_confirmation'),
```